# How can I correctly set the type of a value in the onChange method in React with TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, react-aria

I use React Aria Components' [`RadioGroup`](https://react-spectrum.adobe.com/react-aria/RadioGroup.html) with [controlled values](https://react-spectrum.adobe.com/react-aria/RadioGroup.html#controlled-value) to display an array of options. The options are typed with an `enum`. To store the selected option locally, I use a `useState` with the first option as a default value.

However I get `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Option>'.` with this code:

```tsx
import { useState } from "react";
import { Label, Radio, RadioGroup } from "react-aria-components";

enum Option {
  ONE = "option_one",
  TWO = "option_two",
}

export default function App() {
  const options: Option[] = [Option.ONE, Option.TWO];
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(options[0]);

  return (
    <RadioGroup
      onChange={(value) => setSelectedOption(value)}
      value={selectedOption}
    >
      <Label>Options</Label>
      {options.map((option) => (
        <Radio key={option} value={option}>
          {option}
        </Radio>
      ))}
    </RadioGroup>
  );
}
```

The `useState` id correctly inferred as `Option`, but the `value` is considered a `string`.

[Minimum reproduction sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/rac-radio-group-typescript-7fqkvc?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clraiu70f00063b6iq7x57j0m%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clraiu70f00023b6i5jix6axv%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clraiu70f00033b6i50ww6s7b%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clraiu70f00053b6i7snp303f%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clraiu70f00023b6i5jix6axv%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clraiu70f00013b6iuqe5drgw%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpublic%252Findex.html%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clraiu70f00023b6i5jix6axv%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clraiu70f00013b6iuqe5drgw%2522%257D%252C%2522clraiu70f00053b6i7snp303f%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clraiu70f00043b6ili2eblic%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clraiu70f00053b6i7snp303f%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clraiu70f00043b6ili2eblic%2522%257D%252C%2522clraiu70f00033b6i50ww6s7b%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clraiu70f00033b6i50ww6s7b%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

The only thing working so far seems to be a type assertion like:

```tsx
export default function App() {
  // ...

  return (
    <RadioGroup
      onChange={(value) => setSelectedOption(value as Option)}
      value={selectedOption}
    >
      // ...
    </RadioGroup>
  );
}
```

I generally try to avoid type assertions. Is there another smoother way to get the right type for the `onChange` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're starting with a string (`value`), you have to tell TypeScript you know it's a valid `Option`. There are at least two ways to do this:

1. Use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) or an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions).
2. Use a type assertion.

I prefer using a type predicate or assertion function since it not only satisfies TypeScript, but also checks things at runtime so that if I make a mistake (for instance: adding a hardcoded "none" option to the list that isn't in `Option`), I get a clear error I can fix. Here you probably want an assertion function, since there isn't a valid code path where the value wouldn't be correct:

```
function assertIsOption(value: string): asserts value is Option {
    if (!Object.keys(Option).includes(value)) {
        throw new Error(`Invalid Option value: "${value}"`);
    }
}
```

*(There are various ways to spin that; the point is just that it's an assertion function that checks `value`.)*

Then use it in your click handler:

```
<RadioGroup onChange={(value) => {
    assertIsOption(value);
    setSelectedOption(value);
}} value={selectedOption}>
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxJwC+cAZlBCHAERSoYsDcAUKJLFxwAMigBGSADbYEKACbAIM+YoDijfGBr1GzNhxgBaFFGApDaJpAB2SazELcePO-mYB5MDEXXcPOAFw7gByAKJwALysEF4+APoQtiyY-oEAKgDq7pHRsYlxMADuEMk81M50+NYYPnAohMSwAJKEnt6JABQAbiiS+EgAXHCEMKbWAOYAlEP1jQ5wPX1UwIRBeb44qQHAdHAdAITuYgBWSBgAdADWSACehB1tPpPnwNV9ckj3i-2Tk36BALgMAAFoxCnBbODQlBGFAOgADJrWRbAORrdq+b6DVgAEhwWOoLHhk14APK5RcAA8BPAPnQUPhJPBKtUMXAAIJgMAdP6bAGWawjOAxDGEIaPRIAbQAujlJRLrOcQqFsArzpl3NLSYEBULJcRJGdKHIFdhiDASFIjUgTetZVEiKRyJQOiKfIRJQAGaUk5wA9gwfBQXwdLaAgA8sgUEHUEE0wusAGFgSgJkgIjhur0fpEAHz-QGF2ZIZqtdZZpa+wuF82Ww0YG0Kis-bWF6i0LEZg3W20Y6i5sPVuDh0QSSS5hWEcMAelHUgHQ4BODdiUI5xAKG5rvWfwi+dDi+rkZUEDg1xuGZX1g72fTy-W-cHh8B977T8PM6jigXz9+5SHn4nrGmg-gEvrUEAA) (note: it takes a **long** time for the playground to finish loading the libs).